# Parallel writer and reader of std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, vector, c++11

I have a class that is used by 2 threads at the same time: one thread adds results (one by one) to the `results` of a task, the second thread works on those `results` that are already there.

```
// all members are copy-able
struct task {
    command cmd;
    vector<result> results;
};

class generator {
    public:
        generator(executor* e); // store the ptr
        void run();
        ...
};

class executor {
    public:
        void run();
        void add_result(int command_id, result r);
        task& find_task(int command_id);
            ...
    private:
        vector<task> tasks_;
        condition_variable_any update_condition_;
};
```

**Launch**

```
// In main, we have instances of generator and executor,
// we launch 2 threads and wait for them.
std::thread gen_th( std::bind( &generator::run, gen_instance_) );
std::thread exe_th( std::bind( &executor::run,  exe_instance_) );
```

**Generator Thread**

```
void generator::run() {
    while(is_running) {
        sleep_for_random_seconds(); 
        executor_->add_result( SOME_ID, new_result() );
    }
}
```

**Executor thread**

```
void executor::add_result( int command_id, result r ) {
    std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> l(mutex_);
    task& t = this->find_task(command_id);
    t.results.push_back(r);
    update_condition_.notify_all();
}

void executor::run() { 
  while(is_running) {
     update_condition_.wait(...);
     task& t = this->find_task(SOME_ID);        
     for(result r: t.results) {
        // no live updates are visible here
     }
   }
}
```

1. Generator thread adds a result every few seconds.
2. Executor thread is an `executor` itself. It is run via the `run` method, which waits for an update and when that happens, it works on the results.

Few things to take notice of:

1. vector of tasks may be big; the results are never disposed;
2. the `for-each` loop in executor fetches the task it's working on, then iterates over results, checks which of them are new and processes them. Once processed, they are marked and won't be processed again. This processing may take some time.

The problem occurs when **Executor Thread** doesn't finish the for loop before another result is added - the result object is not visible in the for loop. Since **Executor Thread** is working, it doesn't notice the update condition update, doesn't refresh the vector etc. When it finishes (working on a *alread-not-actual view* of `tasks_`) it hangs again on the `update_condition_`.. which was just triggered.

I need to make the code aware, that it should run the loop again after finishing it **or** make changes to a task visible in the `for-each` loop. What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Looks like a job for a semaphore, no?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the way I use the `vector`.. The code is quite synchronized (mutexes over semaphores).

Comment: What I don't understand is: how does the executor know about `123`? It is hardcoded in your code for thread 2. There must be some other loop in there, right? Also, if that is inside of `run()` as your comment says, what is the `executor_` variable pointing to? Shouldn't it be `this`?

Comment: This is a classical producer/consumer duo. One thread produces results, another one consumes them. This is the kind of problem a counting semaphore was invented for. It keeps count of things produced but not yet consumed. I don't see a synchronization object that can count in your code. If you don't have such an object, you will eventually end up implementing one.

Comment: I've updated th dedescription, hopefuly it's more accurate now!

Comment: You don't need to use `std::bind` to launch a thread, `std::thread gen_th( &generator::run, gen_instance_ );` works just as well, with less copying

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check whether your vector is empty or not *before* blocking on the CV. Something like that:

```
while (running) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while (tasks_.empty()) // <-- this is important
        update_condition_.wait(lock);
    // handle tasks_
}
```

If your architecture allows it (ie. if you don't need to hold the lock while handling the tasks), you may also want to unlock the mutex ASAP, before handling the tasks so that the producer can push more tasks without blocking. Maybe swapping your `tasks_` vector with a temporary one, then unlock the mutex, and only then start handling the tasks in the temporary vector:

```
while (running) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while (tasks_.empty())
        update_condition_.wait(lock);
    std::vector<task> localTasks;
    localTasks.swap(tasks_);
    lock.unlock(); // <-- release the lock early
    // handle localTasks
}
```

**Edit:** ah now I realize this doesn't really fit your situation, because your messages are not directly in `tasks_` but in `tasks_.results`. You get my general idea though, but using it will require structure changes in your code (eg. flatten your tasks / results and always have a cmd associated with a single result).

Comment: the `if` should be a `while` to handle spurious wake-ups

Answer (score 0):

I act in the following way in the same situation

```
std::vector< ... > temp;
mutex.lock();
temp.swap( results );
mutex.unlock();
for(result r: temp ){
    ...
}
```

A little overhead takes a place, but in general whole code is more readeble and if an amount of calculations is big, then the time for copying goes to zero (sorry for english - it's not native to me)))

Comment: The problem with your code is that if your tasks vector (what you called `results` here) is empty then you're basically busy-looping. This is why condition_variables are very useful. ;)

Comment: I showed only the rest of code. Of course thread should wait some condition and then work with data